# .htaccess redirect questions

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm redirecting my website from my old domain to my new one.
Preety much everything is done, I have only 2 questions:

1) The website is a bit different on the new domain (I removed some pages and sections). Is it ok (SEO-wise) to redirect the pages I have on the old domain to the same pages on the new domain and then redirect every other page to the root of the new domain?
So basically, redirect old pages that don't exist anymore to the root of the new domain.

2) How do I do that?

For now I have a bunch of rules like:

```
Redirect 301 /oldfile.html http://www.newdomain.com/newfile.html
```

How do I add a rule to say redirect tha pages as instructed above AND redirect every other page to the root of the new domain?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Could you make up your mind in asking just a single question per question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, it's good.

2) You can't, you'll have to select the folder root you want to redirect to your domain root for bulk redirect if you want to be sure of what you do.

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ domain.xxx [R=301,L]
```

Comment: tnx very much.. I ended up using this for the "and everything else" rule => RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(rates|orders|links|about|services).html